# EOFException, or SocketException: Socket is closed, when transfer file via socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing a simple file tranfer app between client and server.
Here is my code:
My Client(Sender):

```
try{
                File file_sender=XMLParser.register(peername, address, port, listfile);
                int count;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len=(int) file_sender.length();
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[len];     
                DataOutputStream output=new DataOutputStream(Info.connection.getOutputStream());
                output.writeInt(len);
                System.out.println(len);
                BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file_sender));
                bis.read(mybytearray, 0, len);
                output.write(mybytearray, 0, len);
                bis.close();
                output.close();
               // Info.connection.close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
```

My server(Receiver):

```
public class IOThread extends Thread {
private Socket connection;
private DataInputStream input;
public IOThread(Socket connection) throws IOException{
    this.connection=connection;
    input=new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

}
@Override
public void run(){
    while(true){
        try{
            int filesize=12022386;
            int bytesRead;
            int currentTot = 0;
            byte[] bytearray = new byte [filesize];
            int len=input.readInt();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data.xml");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead=input.read(bytearray, 0,bytearray.length);
            System.out.println(len);
            currentTot=bytesRead;
            do{
                bytesRead=input.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot));
                if(bytesRead>=0) currentTot+=bytesRead;
                System.out.println("pos: "+currentTot);
            } while(len!=currentTot);
            bos.write(bytearray, 0, currentTot);
            bos.close();
            //connection.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        }catch(EOFException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            break;
        }catch( Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

**I want to tranfer more than one file**, so I don't want to close socket. So, I use variable "len" to check the file is tranfered completely.

If I close "output" after send file then server thows EOFException and the file is sent success.

When I don't close output, server can't receive file success. But Server doesn't throws EOFException.

Can you help me solve this problem?
Update: Here is my output on the console screen if I don't close variable "output" at client:

246

pos: 496

Thanks.
*Sorry for my poor English*

Comment: How exactly does the server not receive the file successfully if you don't close the socket? Does it get stuck in the loop?

Comment: Your title is misleading. EOFException and 'socket is closed' are two separate conditions, not one.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First of all, you seem to be ignoring the file length in your receiving code? You have:

```
        int filesize=12022386;
        int bytesRead;
        int currentTot = 0;
        byte[] bytearray = new byte [filesize];
        int len=input.readInt();
```

You are sizing bytearray to 12022386 bytes regardless of the value of `len`, and you are asking for that many bytes from the input stream.

Secondly, when you close the output stream, any cached/buffered data that hasn't been written yet is automatically flushed (i.e., in your case, sent to the server).

Flush the output stream explicitly when you're done sending the first file to force it to finish sending all of the data to the server. You can then continue using that output stream for other things.

Do `output.flush()` in your sending code when the transfer is complete.

Comment: I added output.flush() after sending file complete at client but the server still can't receive successfully.

Comment: See my comment re: `filesize`. Use your value for `len` instead. Your `read` call could be blocking trying to read 12022386 bytes. Also, according to your output, you read a bit more than the length of the file (file length 246 but you read at least 496).

Comment: huhuhuhuhuhuhu , Thank you very very very very very very much. Stackoverflow is greate.

Comment: You should also consider reading using the `readFully` method. See my answer below.

Comment: @user1956702 In addition to 'huhuhuhu', you can show your gratitude to JasonC by accepting his answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you read beyond the size of your file, i.e. instead of reading `len` bytes, you read `bytearray.length` bytes, which is larger.

Consequently, you read more than `len` bytes, so `len!=currentTot` is never satisfied, because, as you can see from your sample output, `currentTot == 496` and `len == 246`.

Make the following changes in your while loop:

```
do{
   bytesRead=input.read(bytearray, currentTot, (len - currentTot));
   if(bytesRead>=0) currentTot += bytesRead;
   System.out.println("pos: " + currentTot);
} while(len != currentTot);
```

Just to make sure you don't end up in an endless loop due to a similar error, you could use `currentTot < len` instead of `len != currentTot` as your condition.

Also, since you're already using `DataInputStream`, consider reading the socket contents using `readFully`. This blocks until a given number of bytes is read from the socket, essentially eliminating your need for the while loop. Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).

Answer (score 2):

Throw all the loops away and use `DataInputStream.readFully();` close the socket after sending the file; don't s end the file length; and use a normal size buffer, say 8192 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BufferedOutputStream` filling seems incorrect. Below code must be inside the while loop.

```
bos.write(bytearray, 0, currentTot);
```

Try something like this instead:

```
BufferedOutputStream buffOut=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
byte []arr = new byte [1024 * 1024];
int available  = -1;
while((available = buffIn.read(arr)) != -1) { 
    buffOut.write(arr, 0, available); 
}      
buffOut.flush();
buffOut.close();
```

And test again.

Edit: Updated my answer with @Jason's correct comment.

Comment: You should test `>= 0`, not `> 0`, as 0 is a valid return value for `read` and does not indicate the end of input (it indicates that no data is available at the moment and the underlying stream would block, essentially meaning "try again later").

Comment: I have edited my code follow your instruction. But string " Done" don't display on my console screen at server, mean that can't get out of the while loop.

Comment: @JasonC That's not correct. InputStream.read() only returns zero if the length specified was zero, which is a programming error. If no data is available it will block. Zero does not mean 'try again later'.